# How many isometries in R3 that...

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, isometry

In the euclidian field $R^3$, how many isometries  apply $(1,0,0)$ on $(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ on $(0,0,1)$ ?

I am tempted to answer only one, the one which apply $(0,0,1)$ on $(-\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2,0)$ but I feel like there should be more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about isomotries of the metric space, there are infinitely many. If you talk about *linear* isometries, there are two. If you talk about linear *orientation-preserving* isomoetries, then there is only one.

Comment: I am talking about linear isometries. 

Are the two isometries the one that apply : 

$(0,0,1)$ on $(-\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2,0)$ 

and the one that apply: $(0,0,1)$ on $(\sqrt{2}/2,-\sqrt{2}/2,0)$ ?